# Encryption in an open-source program?

Tags: node.js, security, ssl, encryption, webserver

Currently I'm developing a Node.js webserver-app that I then want to make available for download and use. This app should feature accounts, so that you can log in with your account on the website created by the server.
Since that would require a password, I also have to think about security obviously. But now, I don't really know **how** I should protect the password while sending and receiving it.

For storage, I was about to simply create a hash of the password and store that hash somewhere, but what about the transfer?

I was thinking about SSL/https, but this would require a SSL certificate, and even if I got it for free somewhere, I couldn't share it in an open-source app(?).

I could also somehow hash the password in the website, and then just send the hash to the server, but I think this wouldn't be the highest standard of security as well, would it? Considering that no SSL would cause more disadvantages than just worse/none encryption.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking about SSL/https, but this would require a SSL certificate, and even if I got it for free somewhere, I couldn't share it in an open-source app(?).

Use SSL/TLS. Even if it's an open source app, it doesn't mean that you need to share your private key too. This would undermine the whole concept.

Open source means that you share the code with some license. What the licensor does with it is not your consern as long as they conform to the license. If they want to use their own instance of your software under their own domain, they *will* have to create their own certificate (under their domain).

> I could also somehow hash the password in the website, and then just send the hash to the server, but I think this wouldn't be the highest standard of security as well, would it? Considering that no SSL would cause more disadvantages than just worse/none encryption.

This is no solution, because you now changed the thing you want to protect to something else. The model doesn't change just because you hash it on the client. Now you need to protect the hash on the transport channel which is actually the same problem as you would have had before with sending a password.

> Currently I'm developing a Node.js webserver-app that I then want to make available for download and use. This app should feature accounts, so that you can log in with your account on the website created by the server.

**Federated accounts**

If you want federated accounts across multiple instances of your app which are hosted by different parties.

You could look into OpenID as an identity provider for all instances of your app. You would then either require that users use a known OpenID provider or you setup your own default provider. You could release the code for your provider as open source, but it wouldn't be necessary for the app to function.

If the OpenID interface is not enough, there is always a way to establish a pairing between instances of your app. You would have to build an interface where different instances may share data.

**Unconnected instances**

If this is only about securing the communication without SSL/TLS, then I must say, this is impossible in the general sense.

You could however let every student register in person and use that password on client and server to derive a shared secret key (i.e. for AES). Then you could use CryptoJS to encrypt everything with AES and send it using AJAX. The problems are of course that (1) there must be a person that handles the registration and (2) this is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks, because [JavaScript crypto is bad](http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/).

Good thing is that [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) will be online soon. It will enable a semi-automated way to request free certificates for your domain. It will be so easy that you can do this as part of the normal NPM install workflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's actually for hosting homework information, I'll use it for my own school and thought others could use it as well on their schools if it gets any useful soon, so I made it open-source. The idea was that you, as a student, could be authorised on the server of your school running my software to edit information on the database, so your account would be created on the server of the particular school, and you could only sign in with it on exactly that server. So I'm concerned that it's too much for schools to get a SSL certificate instead of just typing npm install and npm run

Comment: There is really no other general and secure way besides requiring SSL/TLS. You could however let every student register in person and use that password on client and server to derive a shared secret key (i.e. for AES). Then you could use CryptoJS to encrypt everything with AES and send it using AJAX. The problems are of course that (1) there must be a person that handles the registration and (2) this is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks, because [JavaScript crypto is bad](http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/). Good thing is that https://letsencrypt.org is online soon.

Answer (score 1):

http://letsencrypt.org works great for this and is now available (I understand I am a little late to this one.)

You can check out https://github.com/DylanPiercey/auto-sni for automated Letsencrypt certificates.